# Extending built in image block of gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I am on wodpress 5.2 with *twenty-ten* theme. This means there is a lot of places where gutenberg generated content is broken. I could fix many things in child theme css, yet I want embedded images looking like old ones. I am looking for short and clean way to inherit what built-in image block offers and make custom image with same editor options yet slightly modified HTML fragment generated by that block, applying custom classes to `figure` and `figcaption` for a start.

Comment: I would try and see if it works in a newer theme first. Does it work in a newer theme? That's getting pretty old now isn't it?

Comment: I know it is old, yet my child theme is so heavily customized that I grown idea it is easier to fix last ingredient (image block) than to take new theme and customize again everything. BTW image block works now fine (in newer and old theme), it just looks naked without 'polaroid' frame as in old version. So my idea is to add `wp-caption` class to these two tags in automated way so it looks exactly as before.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options (at least).

#### Make your own block

You can grab the [code of the image block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src/image) at github and start creating your own block from it, e.g. using [`create-guten-block`](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block). You will need some time (~ 1-2h) to get it working because some import statements and other things must be adapted, it's not only copy and past.

=> Use it if you need lots of customizations to what the image block can offer and you want to get to the heart of block creation, altering functions, behavior, appearance, anything.

#### Edit the existing block in a filter

Gutenberg offers many new filters, e.g. the `blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps` filter. It lets you manipulate the blocks properties, such as the classes.

```
function addBlockClassName( props, blockType ) {
    if(blockType.name === 'core/image') {
        return Object.assign( props, { class: 'wp-caption' } );
    }
    return props;
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps',
    'some-custom-name/add-block-class-name',
    addBlockClassName
);
```

Comment: Thanx for tips, as soon as I get more time to setup toolset and familiarize myself with whole process I will be back to this subject. I hoped there is some shorter way like it was done before by creating php code by hand. Using webpack and whotnot for wordpress sound like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: @andy if an answer is correct, mark it as correct and upvote it, to show the community the value